# How do I make a notification table that makes eloquent relationships to other tables without making too many "<source>_id" columns

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Suppose that I have a Notification Table that gets generated when a new log from another table is generated. Suppose I have 3 different logs with different purpose namely: sms_logs, call_logs, and appointment_logs.

I want to make a relationship to each logs without using sms_logs_id, call_logs_id and appointment_logs_id. Instead, I want to build only two columns, one for the type, and the other for the ID. So for example an sms log is generated with an id of 187, it will also generate a notification log with a notification_id of 187 and a type of "sms".

How will I be able to create that? Thank you!

Comment: Have you read [the Laravel documentation about Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)?

Comment: I do think this is the answer. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

You have to put only two fields in `notifications` table. `foreign_id` and `log_type`.

Whenever you add a log, you have to set `log_type` accordingly. Then add this relationship in your `Notification` model.

```
    public function foreignModel()
    {
        switch($this->log_type){
            case "call_log":
                return $this->belongsTo('App\Call', 'foreign_id');
                break;
        }

    }
```

I didn't tried it, but hope it will work fine.

If you are looking for something more dynamic and less robust than this then I don't think that it exists.